# Use a class function as a default parameter when the object is a parameter itself

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

I don't know if it's possible but I'd like to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
int search(T array, int first = 0, int last = array.size())
{

}
```

Here T should be a container and I'd like to know its size and use it as a default parameter. Is that possible?

Edit: yep, made a mistake its not T but array.

Comment: `.size()` has to be applied to an object of the type, not the type name itself.

Comment: I think you meant `array.size()` not `T.size()`.  After fixing that, I think you still need a separate overload.  I also would frequently like to use `array.size()` there.  But I'm pretty sure you can't.

Comment: @JSF `array.size()` would not work either

Comment: @Slava, the fact that changing that doesn't fix the code, is no reason to avoid fixing the question.  We think changing that provides the intended question.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. There is no way to keep it compact in a simple function?

Comment: @Wylex there is better way - pass 2 iterators, instead of container and 2 indexes as it is done in standard algos

Comment: @Slava That would be the same at the end. What I'm looking for is to make an algorithm that search the index of a given key in a sorted array by recursion. In the main function you should just give the container and the key. The function then should by recursion reduce the area of the container (last and first arguments), find the key and return the index.

Comment: @Wylex, no that would not the same, for example when you use 2 iterators you can pass "C style" array to that function, in your approach you cannot.

Comment: @Slava Yes but what I mean is that you would have to pass 2 arguments to the function instead of one.

Comment: @Wylex do you mean 2 arguments instead of 3? Do not forget, when you pass iterators, you do not need to pass container itself.

Comment: @Slava I mean that I'd need to pass 2 iterators plus the key (yes, 3 arguments). Otherwise I'd just have to pass the container and the key (the container has itself the size() function). You can't pass C style array but I don't find them very useful.

Comment: @Wylex one day you will find that you want to search for a key not in whole array, but in part. And your function does not work anymore. Plus algorithms using iterators more generic, they can work with `std::istream_iterator` etc. Your function would be very limited in that sense. But it is up to you of course.

Comment: @Slava I'm just trying to make the algorithm to learn a bit how recursion works. Anyway I guess you're right I'll try to do it your way ;)

Comment: If you want the same entry point for the original call and the recursive call, it is easiest to just change the meaning of the third param: `int search(T array, int first = 0, int rfirst = 0) { int last=array.size()-rfirst; ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `T.size()` since `T` is not an object.

You can use function overloads to accomplish what you are trying.

```
template <typename T>
int search(T const& array, int first, int last)
{
}

template <typename T>
int search(T const& array, int first = 0)
{
   return search(array, first, array.size());
}
```

**PS** I changed the type of the array to `T const&` from `T`. This will prevent making copies when the function(s) gets called.

Comment: Array should be passed as const reference to avoid copying

Comment: To fit the intended question, I think it should be passed `&&` (to the 2 input overload) then forwarded.

Comment: @JSF, My guess is that the OP hadn't thought about those differences.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Instead you should replace the last default parameter to normal parameter, and pass the size of container while calling the function, e.g.,

```
template <typename T>
int search(T array, int last, int first=0)
{
    // you can also directly use array.size() here, 
    // so no need for extra parameter
}

vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);

// call search
search< vector<int> >(v, v.size());
```